# Funtion $y=x^{x^x}$. Find $y'$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let $f(x)=x^x, x>0$.

Then $f(x)=e^{x\ln x}$ and $f'(x)=e^{x\ln x}(\ln x+1)$.

What about $g(x)=x^{x^x}$? How find $g'(x)$?

Comment: $g(x)=x^f(x)$, so $g(x)=e^{f \ln x}$.  Use the chain rule.

Comment: You can further simplify your answer for $f$ as $f'(x)=e^{x\ln x}(\ln x+1) = x^x(\ln x + 1)$

Comment: What is the derivative of $x^{x^{\cdots^x}}, \, (n \text{ of them})?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(x)=e^{f(x) \ln x}.$$

$$g^\prime(x) = \left(\frac{f(x)}{x} + f^\prime(x) \ln x\right) g(x).$$

You have shown that $$f^\prime = f(x)\cdot (\ln x +1),$$ so

$$g^\prime(x) = f(x)\cdot g(x)\cdot \left( \frac{1}{x} + \ln x \cdot( \ln x +1 )\right)$$

$$g^\prime(x) = x^x \cdot x^{x^x} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{x} + \ln x \cdot( \ln x +1 )\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply $\ln$ to both sides:$$y=x^{x^x} \\ \ln y = x^x\ln x $$ Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:$$ \frac{y'}{y} = {(x^x)'}\ln x + x^x\frac{1}{x} \\ y' = x^{x^x}(\color{red}{(x^x)'}\ln x + x^x\frac{1}{x})$$
Then, plug in what you said you already $\color{red}{\text{know}}$.

Comment: Very nice.  You can take it one step further:  $\ln \ln y = \ln \ln x + x \ln x$ and then differentiate.

Comment: @mjw Thank you. That is a nice suggestion. I just wanted to connect it with OP's try, in the end. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: You are welcome.  I did the same thing (using OP's expression for $f^\prime)$.  Anyway, I took my own advice and saw that it is consistent with our other solutions.

Comment: @mjw Yes, it is nice!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the question is asked. Answer changes for $(x^x)^x$ and $x^{(x^x)}$.

Comment: The question is not ambiguous but clearly stated as $x^{x^x}$.

Comment: It is generally excepted that $x^{x^x}=x^{(x^x)}$